# How can identify a google search with zero results using bs4 and requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to identify if a google search returns zero results or not. The current code I am using is attempting to identify if the google fishing image is there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = input("Input the domain of the top level domain: ")
textsearch = input("Input what text you're looking for: ")

r = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A.{site}+%22{textsearch}%22")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
search = soup.find(attrs = {"xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"})
print(search)
```

The current code is just returning "none" when I give it a TLD and text that returns zero results. If there is a more optimal way to do this please inform more! Or if there is something I can fix in this code that would be great too.

Comment: when using request vs browser, try to see what the soup looks like , for example save the soup as `with open("my_soup.html","w") as fh:
    fh.write(str(soup))` , and once you open this HTML file, you will see that the following code would work. `if soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("did not match any documents")'):
    print("No search results")`

Comment: what simpleApp said, but also, you could try `if not soup.select('a h3'): print("No search results")` or `print(len(soup.select('a h3')), 'results on page 1')`, etc